# Matrix of traveling time between multiple locations

Tags: online-resources, driving, maps

I'm looking for some online resources that would allow me to select 10 locations (e.g., 10 cities or 10 landmarks in a city), and would return the time it takes to drive/walk/use public transportation between each pair of location. (i.e, the resource would return a 10x10 matrix where each cell i,j represents the time it takes to go from i to j).

Comment: Globally or US only ?

Comment: The Google Distance Matrix API does pretty much exactly this, but it's meant for developers, not end users: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start

Comment: Wouldn’t it be more useful if it just solves TSP for you?

Comment: @Hilmar globally but US is one of my main interests

Comment: @JonathanReez I actually don't plan to visit all nodes, just to get a sense of the travel distance between each pair.

Comment: @lambshaanxy thanks, looks great, you're welcome to post it as an answer

Comment: You need to open an account to use Google Distance Matrix API. It used to be free, but now there is a free usage bandwidth allowance. Above this usage limit your requests are billed to you.

Answer (score 5):

I've used a [route planner](https://www.drivingrouteplanner.com) that accepts up to 25 places and shows the distance required to visit all of them driving.  Lets you select many different routes, for comparison.  Also lets you say how much time you want to spend in each place, for a total time estimate. And it lists each route in a format similar to a railroad timetable, so you can see how long each leg takes.

Comment: This is a route planner for calculating a single route between cities, not the distance matrix requested by the OP.

Comment: It will show the distance for each leg, AND it allows selecting different routes to get different pair of cities.  Thus, it provides all the information to put into such a matrix.  Since nothing else has been offered, it's the closest thing I know of.  It's a bit easier than individually looking up each pair separately.